# sequelize multiple foreign key includes only one column

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i have made two foreign keys from user table.

```
db.Subscription.belongsTo(db.User, {foreignKey: 'creatorId'});
db.Subscription.belongsTo(db.User, {foreignKey: 'subscriberId'});
```

during search query i get `subscriberId` column included instead of `creatorId`

```
Subscription.findAll({
    where: {
      subscriberId: req.decoded._id
    },
    include: [
      {
          model: User, 
          foreignKey: 'creatorId', 
          attributes: ['name', 'role', 'uid', 'imageUrl']
      }
    ]
})
```

can someone please find out what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try setting a name for the associations so Sequelize has a better idea which association to include.  You can do something like this to set the names on the associations...

```
db.Subscription.belongsTo(db.User, {
  as: 'creator',
  foreignKey: 'creatorId'
});

db.Subscription.belongsTo(db.User, {
  as: 'subscriber',
  foreignKey: 'subscriberId'
});
```

Then you can use those names in the query to get the specific association, as so...

```
Subscription.findAll({
  include: {
    model: User,
    as: 'creator',
    attributes: ['name', 'role', 'uid', 'imageUrl']
  },
  where: {
    subscriberId: req.decoded._identer
  }
});
```

When you have associations to the same table more than once setting a name helps the ORM determine which association to load.  For the record, for all of the records that get returned you can access that association by accessing the `.creator` on the instance.

Good luck! :)