# Eagerly load a belongsTo relation in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Say I have the following relation:

```
User.belongsTo(Image, { foreignKey: 'profileImage' })
Image.hasOne(User, { foreignKey: 'profileImage' })
```

If I call `User.findOne()`, I get:

```
> User.findOne()
User {
  ...
  profileImage: 1 // image_id
}
```

How can I instead load the image, something like this:

```
> User.findOne({ ... })
User {
  ...
  profileImage: Image {
    id: 1 // image_id
    ...
  }
}
```

I have tried passing in options to `.findOne()` using the docs [here](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel) but can't get it working.

I could construct a raw join or run multiple queries, but I feel there should be a nice way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `include` option like this

```js
User.findOne({
  include:[{
    model: Image
  }]
})
```

See [Eager loading](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/)

Comment: This would be the answer if my model association was `User.hasOne(Image)` or `User.hasMany(Image)`, but my model association is `User.belongsTo(Image)`

Comment: This solves my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45470475/4699289. Thanks for pointing me to the Eager loading docs

Comment: The include option will work the same way for any type of associations from `User` to `Image`